# How to save viewpager page position as bookmark?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, position, bookmarks

I have MainActivity where i define viewpager and i also define button on toolbar.
I want when i click on button it save the viewpager page position with title in another activity in listview. 
Provide complete example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is meant to help you with programming problems, not to provide you complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving position of viepager in a **shared preference**.

**save when going away from activity**

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("viepager_position", postion);
        editor.apply();
```

**retrieve when user comes back to activity**

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        int position = prefs.getInt("viepager_position",default_position);
```